# Drawing all lines between a set of points

Tags: graphics

Given that I have the array of points,

```
{{680*4, 509*4}, {739*4, 622*4}, {644*4, 741*4}, {606*4, 
  856*4}, {749*4, 474*4}, {977*4, 542*4}, {601*4, 481*4}, {584*4, 
  604*4}, {866*4, 667*4}}
```

what would be the best way to draw all the possible lines between this set of points and overlay them onto an image?

Comment: `Graphics@Line@Subsets[#, {2}] &@ array` and then use `Show` to cobine it with image.

Comment: @Kuba straightforward, but why not answer?

Comment: @Kuba Is there a place where I can learn to use this kind of shorthand? ATM I am unsure of the correct method to parse this kind of code.

Comment: @MarchHo Here ;) [common pitfalls](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/5478)

Comment: @YvesKlett ok, done. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
array = {{680*4, 509*4}, {739*4, 622*4}, {644*4, 741*4}, {606*4, 
   856*4}, {749*4, 474*4}, {977*4, 542*4}, {601*4, 481*4}, {584*4, 
   604*4}, {866*4, 667*4}};

pic = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], {4000}];


Show[{
  pic,
  Graphics[{Yellow, Line@Subsets[array, {2}] }]
  }, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]